# Recursive Lisp parser with Ocaml Opal

Tags: parsing, ocaml

I'm trying to write a simple Lisp parser with OCaml Opal:

This is my AST:

```
type atom = Num of int | Ident of string [@@deriving show]
type sexp = Atom of atom | ListSexp of sexp list [@@deriving show]
```

And this is the parser:

```
open Opal
open Ast

let integer = many1 digit => implode % int_of_string => fun n -> Atom (Num n)
let ident = many alpha_num => implode => fun i -> Atom (Ident i)
let parens = between (token "(") (token ")")
let atom = integer <|> ident
let expr = parens (sep_by atom space)

let parse_expr input =
  match parse expr input with
  | Some ans -> List.iter (fun a -> Printf.printf "%s" (show_sexp a)) ans
  | None -> print_endline "ERROR!"
```

This works ok when I try to parse `Parser.parse_expr (LazyStream.of_string "(5 3 abc)")`

However, the next thing I tried is to parse S-Expressions recursively by naively modifying my `expr` function to:

```
let rec expr = parens (sep_by (atom <|> expr) space)
```

And this produces an error:

```
8 | let rec expr = parens (sep_by (atom <|> expr) space)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type char input -> (sexp list * char input) option
       but an expression was expected of type
         char input -> (sexp * char input) option
       Type sexp list is not compatible with type sexp
```

This seems ok since `atom` function returns `char input -> (sexp * char input) option` while `expr` function returns `char input -> (sexp list * char input) option`.

But I'm not sure how can to fix this. Ideas?

Comment: You don't use the ListSexp constructor?

Comment: @coredump What do you mean?

Comment: a value of type sexp is either an Atom or a ListSexp, you produce `Atom` values for numbers and identifiers, but then you return `sexp list` directly, which is not of type `sexp`

Comment: You mean like this: `let expr = parens (sep_by atom space) => fun l -> ListSexp l`. I tried, but how to apply the function recursively on this? I got:
`
8 | let rec expr = parens (sep_by (atom <|> expr) space) => fun l -> ListSexp l
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This kind of expression is not allowed as right-hand side of `let rec'
`
error

Comment: @coredump Oh wow! Actually, I made it work. This: `let rec expr input =
  (parens (sep_by (expr <|> atom) space) => fun l -> ListSexp l) input` compiles and parses expressions recursively. You can make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap `sexp lisp` in a `ListSexp` constructor so that it can be of type `sexp`, otherwise you have two conflicting types, `sexp` which is either an `Atom` or a `ListSexp`, and `sexp list`.

You tested the following, and it works:

```
let rec expr input = 
  (parens (sep_by (expr <|> atom) space) => fun l -> ListSexp l) input
```

But I think an expression is not always a list, in EBNF notation I would write:

```
EXPR := ATOM | "(" EXPR* ")"
```

So maybe something like this instead?

```
let rec expr input =
  (parens (sep_by expr space) => (fun l -> ListSexp l) <|> atom) input
```

Comment: Yes. The second approach is better. The correct function would be: `let rec expr input =
  (parens (sep_by expr space) => (fun l -> ListSexp l) <|> atom) input`